# What is the right way to create projects in Django ? (Folders)

Tags: django

Sorry for the weird question.

I am creating a MMORPG Text browser game, and I feel like my project is wrong.
I am creating a new app for everything I need (Account app, Menu app, Fight app). And when I browse Github, people only have like 5/6 folders while I'm at 20 currently.

Where should I put my classes/forms/things normally ? Like, where should I have my fight system placed ?

Thanks ! (Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it's completely up to you how you structure your project. But the common thinking is to make Django app reusable (check [this out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/)) and separate concerns.

For instance, when creating a Django project I follow these steps:

1. **For every new feature, start a new app**, which has its own models, views, templates, static content etc.
2. **Create a separate app called core**, to store some general functionality and static files.
3. **Create a test folder instead of a single test.py**. This folder has separate modules `test_views.py`, `test_models`, `test_forms.py`.
4. **Create a settings folder** which contains `base` settings general to all environments (i.e. development, testing, production) and then specific settings file for every environment.

I noticed, that this basic structure helps to maintain the order and decouples logic even though the project sometimes contains 15+ apps. If you configure your `settings.py` properly (e.g. add new apps to `INSTALLED_APPS`) Django will be able to put your project together nicely, hence I would say don't worry about the number of folders but look at the **reusability** and **separation of concerns**.

Also, it is difficult to say where your fight system should reside without seeing project architecture but I would guess that it will be split among these different apps and could be connected in the `core` app.